# Cassandra Spark connector does not return any result when running on a single node cluster

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using DSE 5.0.0.
I created the following table on a single node Cassandra cluster:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dummy (
  id uuid,
  txt text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO dummy(id, txt) values (uuid(), 'hello world');
```

Then when I query a specific id using the Spark cassandra connector, I do not get any result:

```
val df = sqlc.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
         .options(Map("table" -> "mytable", "keyspace" -> "myks"))
         .load()

df.show(false)

// +------------------------------------+-----------+
// |id                                  |txt        |
// +------------------------------------+-----------+
// |2b69ddc1-2c15-485d-a30f-1b2d7f86c200|hello world|
// +------------------------------------+-----------+

df.filter("id = '2b69ddc1-2c15-485d-a30f-1b2d7f86c200'").show

// 16/07/28 08:51:43 DEBUG CassandraTableScanRDD: Fetching data for range (token("id") <= ?,List(-9223372036854775808)) with SELECT "id", "txt" FROM "myks"."mytable" WHERE token("id") <= ? AND "id" = ?   ALLOW FILTERING with params [-9223372036854775808,2b69ddc1-2c15-485d-a30f-1b2d7f86c200]
// +---+---+
// | id|txt|
// +---+---+
// +---+---+
```

It looks like the query generated by the connector generates the following bad predicate:

```
     WHERE token("id") <= Long.MinValue
```

By setting a few breakpoints, I found out that the Metadata built by the cassandra driver intentionaly sets the TokenRange to be  ]minToken, minToken]:

```
// com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata, line 671
    private static Set<TokenRange> makeTokenRanges(List<Token> ring, Token.Factory factory) {
        ImmutableSet.Builder<TokenRange> builder = ImmutableSet.builder();
        // JAVA-684: if there is only one token, return the range ]minToken, minToken]
        if (ring.size() == 1) {
            builder.add(new TokenRange(factory.minToken(), factory.minToken(), factory));
```

If I modify the driver's code above to return ]minToken, ring(0)], my dataframe returns the expected result.
Could it be a bug in the Cassandra driver and/or connector, or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Is _single node cluster_ in any way meaningful here? It looks like an issue with filtering by UUID...

Comment: Yes, the issue occurs only when I run this on a single node cluster. I use a single node cluster in my continuous integration environment.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the range code

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b4a6be18245c67abee5078236c8eef3b58c51f32/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/rdd/partitioner/CassandraPartition.scala#L15-L16
Should be switching the inequality, investigating

Comment: This is working for me on DSE 5.0, Do you have any more info for repo?

Comment: I am using the following docker instance: https://hub.docker.com/r/vinaynayak/dse-docker/